# How to get Visual Studio 2017 to compile TypeScript on build in class library project (new .net core style .csproj)

Tags: typescript, msbuild, visual-studio-2017

Currently running VS 2017 15.3.5 and Typescript 2.5.2 SDK. How do I get TypeScript to compile on build (regular MSBuild). csproj is the new ".net core style" and project type is class library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before seeing the two good answers here this is what I tried:

First tried adding some parts of .csproj that I found referenced when googling and looking at the "old" csproj file (before converting to the new VS2017/.net core style)

```
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.Default.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.Default.props')" />
```

When I closed the solution and re-opened I was presented with a question about TypeScript version for the project was set to 2.3, but 2.5 was available and if I wanted to upgrade the project. I answered yes. Now I got the TypeScript Build 
Tab in project properties which correctly recognized the tsconfig.json file.

I was hoping that compile on build would noW work, but it didn't.

I also added:

```
    <TypeScriptToolsVersion>2.5</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
```

to the first PropertyGroup in .csproj file. This didn't really do anything either.

Then tried adding:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <TypeScriptCompile Include="src\sourcefile.ts" />
</ItemGroup>
```

with TypeScriptCompile elements for all the files to compile. No luck.

Since I already had Gulp set up in the project (and MSBuild was actually used from Gulp to compile the typescript) I decided to switch from MSBuild called from Gulp to using NPM modules "typescript" and "gulp-typescript" in a Gulp task instead:

REMOVED:

```
gulp.task("Build", function () {
return gulp.src('./' + packageName + '.csproj')
    .pipe(msbuild(
        {
            stderr: true,
            stdout: true,
            toolsVersion: 15.0
        }));
});
```

ADDED:

```
var tsProject;
gulp.task("CompileTypeScript", ['NameOfAnotherTaskThatThisTaskDependsOn'], function () {
  var ts = require("gulp-typescript");

  if (!tsProject) {
      tsProject = ts.createProject("tsconfig.json");
  }

  var reporter = ts.reporter.fullReporter();
  var tsResult = tsProject.src()
    .pipe(tsProject(reporter));

  return tsResult.js
    .pipe(gulp.dest(""));
});
```

Then I bound the "CompileTypeScript" Gulp task to Before Build in Visual Studio. Works fine, although I would like to know if this is possible to get to work with the new csproj format as well.

Thanks for good suggestions @Balah and @Joshit, they probably work just fine as well.

EDIT 8.february 2018: Fixed some typos and corrected name of dependent gulp task (was the same name as the task, which doesnt work of course)

For more info, see [this article](https://www.meziantou.net/2017/10/23/compiling-typescript-using-gulp-in-visual-studio)

Comment: You could accept it as an answer. This can be beneficial to other community members reading this thread

Answer (score 5):

[here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/integrating-with-build-tools.html) is a description for more build tools including msbuild:

The simpliest way:

1. Right-Click -> Manage NuGet Packages
2. Search for Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild
3. Hit Install
4. When install is complete, rebuild!

To be able to build set the tsconfig.json as content in the project.

Comment: Thanks, I haven't verified that this works, but if it does I will change my accepted answer to this one. Also, the link you provided is very useful.

Comment: Setting the build action on `tsconfig.json` to `Content` was the missing step for me. Wish the docs had pointed that part out!

Answer (score 4):

Since you want to use MSBuild, you can edit the .csproj file as follows (I'm using TypeScript 2.5):

```
<Target Name="PostBuild" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent">
  <Exec Command="&quot;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\2.5\tsc.exe&quot; -p tsconfig.json" />
</Target>
```

It's not ideal, because that is a hardcoded path, so I suggest adding `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\2.5\` to your Path environment variable. then you can just use a cleaner command: `Command="tsc.exe -p tsconfig.json"`.

Entering the command into the post-build (or pre-build if that's what you're looking for) in the properties window of the project produces the same result.

[image: Post build tsc]

Comment: If you use "$(TscToolPath)\$(TypeScriptEffectiveToolsVersion)\tsc.exe" -p tsconfig.json instead, you don't need a hard coded path or change to your Path environment variable.

Answer (score 2):

If you´ve installed WebEssentials plugin, you´ll find several options under Tools -> Options. I think the default setting is Compile on save. But you can set this option to false and set Compile on build to true.

[image: VS Options]

Hope thats what you looking for.